# How do you call the following value update operation: a=(a+b)/2?

Tags: functions, terminology

I have the following C++ function:

```
void update(float& a, float b) {
    a = (a+b)/2;
}
```

In other words, I assign to `a` the average of `a` and `b`. How to you call this update operation in Mathematics/plain English? Does it have a name?

Why this question?! The following update operation is called "increasing the value of `a`".

```
void increase(float& a, float b) {
    a = a+b;
}
```

In contrast, "update" is too vague and "update + some explanations" is not concise. Calling it "averaging" is misleading since I would call `a = (b+c)/2` that.

P.S. I realize this is probably not the place to ask this question. SO does not seem to be appropriate either.

Comment: Your function replaces $a$ by the average of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Yes, but is there any word to describe that?

Comment: Recursively defined sequence? Recurrence relation?

Comment: I would write the function like `move_halfway(float* origin, float direction)`. It is a strangely specific operation, generally writing `inline float average(float a, float b)` and `a = average(a,b)` is easier to read while compiling into the same binary code.

Comment: `move_halfway` is the best I've heard until now. Thank you, @Abstraction

Comment: @MateenUlhaq this is not a recurrence. It is an "update".

Comment: It seems you don't understand what we mean by recurrence. The "current value" of the variable $a$ (we call this value $a_n$) depends on its previous values. Which is precisely a recurrence.

Comment: Ok. I agree. However, the question was not about that. But about this particular recurrence (i.e. is there a name for it). In the spirit of writing intelligible code, I am looking for more than "update" for the name of this function/procedure. Despite this being a programming related question, I evaluated my chances of getting a satisfying answer from SO as lower than here. "move_halfway" it good enough for me.

Comment: I think a traditional approach of a function with a return value is the way to go. Then, if you really need it, define a closure called `update` which, in the context of one of your classes, will be given the default value of `() => {a = avg(a,b);}`.

Answer (score 1):

I would perhaps call it a [recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation). You can write it as:

$$a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n + b}{2}$$

with a particular seed value $a_0$ and constant $b$.

Comment: This is not a recurrence.

Comment: Yes, it is. Any programming assignment of the form "$v = f(v)$" should be formalized as a sequence $v_n$ satisfying $v_n=f(v_{n-1})$.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.